# How to resolve the "/lib/modules/3.13.0-27-generic/build: No such file or directory" error message?

Tags: kernel, compiling, bug-reporting, make

I'm following the instructions on [this page](https://launchpad.net/~hybrid-graphics-linux) so I can submit enough information about my machine to [this bug report module](http://bugs.launchpad.net/bugs/752542).

I'm stuck in running some of the following commands

```
git clone git://github.com/Lekensteyn/acpi-stuff.git
cd acpi-stuff/acpi_dump_info
make
sudo make load
cat /proc/acpi/dump_info > handles.txt
```

I cloned the Git repository but I can't run the `make` command, I'm getting the following error messages:

```
mg@MG-7520SE:~/workspace/HybridGraphicsCards$ cd acpi-stuff/acpi_dump_info
mg@MG-7520SE:~/workspace/HybridGraphicsCards/acpi-stuff/acpi_dump_info$ make
make -C /lib/modules/3.13.0-27-generic/build M=/home/mg/workspace/HybridGraphicsCards/acpi-stuff/acpi_dump_info modules
make[1]: *** /lib/modules/3.13.0-27-generic/build: No such file or directory.  Stop.
Makefile:9: recipe for target 'default' failed
make: *** [default] Error 2
mg@MG-7520SE:~/workspace/HybridGraphicsCards/acpi-stuff/acpi_dump_info$ sudo make
[sudo] password for mg: 
make -C /lib/modules/3.13.0-27-generic/build M=/home/mg/workspace/HybridGraphicsCards/acpi-stuff/acpi_dump_info modules
make[1]: *** /lib/modules/3.13.0-27-generic/build: No such file or directory.  Stop.
Makefile:9: recipe for target 'default' failed
make: *** [default] Error 2
```

So after cloning the Git repository, I access the specified directory `acpi-stuff/acpi_dump_info` and ran `make` but it didn't work. I tried running it as `sudo` it still didn't work.

I noticed its complaining because there is not `build` directory under the `/lib/modules/3.13.0-27-generic/` directory. I'm not sure what this is exactly but from the looks of it, the `make` command needed a compiled version of my kernel but didn't find one. But I know nothing about that anyway.

I tried installing linux headers by running the commands

1. `sudo apt-get install linux-headers-3.13.0-27-generic`
2. `sudo apt-get install linux-headers-`uname -r`

..but they both failed and had the same output

```
mg@MG-7520SE:~$ sudo apt-get install linux-headers-3.13.0-27-generic
[sudo] password for mg: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package linux-headers-3.13.0-27-generic is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'linux-headers-3.13.0-27-generic' has no installation candidate
```

My system infomration:

```
mg@MG-7520SE:~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.10
Release:    14.10
Codename:   utopic
mg@MG-7520SE:~$ uname -a
Linux MG-7520SE 3.13.0-27-generic #50-Ubuntu SMP Thu May 15 18:06:16 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

So what should I do to be able to run the `make` command successfully under this directory ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was using a kernel (v3.13) that is not meant to be used with the distro version I'm using (Ubuntu 14.10).

So I installed the latest possible kernel for my distro by running the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-generic
```

It fixed my brightness issue too !

Comment: Can someone please explain why this answer is downvoted?

Answer (score 14):

you need to install **linux-headers-3.13.0-27-generic** package

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-3.13.0-27-generic
```

or better

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-`uname -r`
```

this will provide the link /lib/modules/3.13.0-27-generic/build

Comment: It didn't work. Check my question for the output of running these commands.

Comment: what are you running ? ubuntu ? debian ? mint ? try running sudo apt-get update && apt-get dist-upgrade before

Comment: (Ubuntu 14.10)
`uname -a`: `Linux MG-7520SE 3.13.0-27-generic #50-Ubuntu SMP Thu May 15 18:06:16 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`, `lsb_release -a`: `No LSB modules are available, 
Distributor ID: Ubuntu, 
Description: Ubuntu 14.10, 
Release: 14.10, 
Codename: utopic`

Comment: `uname -r` or `$(uname -r)` doesn't work. The header I need is `4.4.0-154-generic` but the command results in `4.4.154`. Moreover, I had to edit Makefile because it also (ab)uses uname

Answer (score 2):

Find where your build-essentials are kept

```
find / | grep include/generated/autoconf.h
```

Mine returned

```
/usr/src/linux-headers-4.19.0-5-amd64/include/generated/autoconf.h
```

If you followed the guides online and they didn't work, replace

```
/lib/modules/`uname -r`/build
```

With the result from above - in my case

```
/usr/src/linux-headers-`uname -r`
```

So, in total

```
obj-m += hello-1.o

all:
    make -C /usr/src/linux-headers-$(shell uname -r) M=$(PWD) modules

clean:
    make -C /usr/src/linux-headers-$(shell uname -r) M=$(PWD) clean
```

Answer (score 1):

had the same problem with using an old kernel.
You need to install -generic headers, for that head to this site:
[https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/](https://kernel.ubuntu.com/%7Ekernel-ppa/mainline/)
And download the Kernel headers for your kernel with `wget url`.
Next run `sudo dpkg -i pakage-name.deb`.
Then try to build. If it doesn't work and you get the `*** /lib/modules/3.13.0-27-generic/build: No such file or directory.` Error message, head over to /lib/modules and check if your headers are named differently. If so, just change the name of them to mach the one looked for by the make program.